# Conditionally Showing Graphs

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bunch of graphs on a single sheet. Also, I have a drop down menu of items. When I choose a particular item, I want to only show the graph associated with that item. How would I do this?

Here is a macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Visible = False
        On Error Resume Next
        ChartObjects(Target.Value).Visible = True
End If
End Sub
```

When I select the item from the drop down menu, I have to click on another cell and then click back on the drop down menu to get the graph to show. How do I get the graph to show instantaneously?

Answer (score 1):

I would create an ActiveX combobox instead (Developers tab->Insert->ComboBox).
Then instead of WorkSheet_Change use ComboBox1_Click() as event handler

You access the selected item with ComboBox1.value (assuming you don't change the default "ComboBox1" name).